# how to search rows which are dynamically created in tablelayout?

Tags: android

How to search rows which are dynamically created in table layout of android? I'm having a table layout which contains name and code as columns, how do i search those rows for particular name/code?

I'm trying to add tag in this way:

```
TextView empFirstName = null; 
    int i,j;
    for (i=0; i<employees.size();i++){

        final Employee employee = (Employee) employees.get(i);

        int count = 0;

        TableRow empData = new TableRow(this);
        empData.setId(300+count);
        empData.setClickable(true);


        /*empData.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT ));*/
        //tr.setClickable(true);

        final TextView empCode = new TextView(this);
        empCode.setId(300+count);
        empCode.setText(employee.getCode());
        empCode.setTextSize(16);
        empCode.setPadding(2,2, 2, 2);
        empCode.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams( 0, android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 2 ));
        empData.addView(empCode);


        final TextView empName = new TextView(this);
        empName.setId(300+count);
        empName.setText(employee.getCallName());
        empName.setTextSize(16);
        empName.setPadding(2, 2, 2, 2);
        empName.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams( 0, android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 4 ));
        empData.addView(empName);

        empFirstName = new TextView(this);
        empFirstName.setId(007);
        empFirstName.setText(employee.getFirstName());
        empFirstName.setTag(i);
```

}

I'm trying to retrieve name this way:

```
for(j=0;j<=i;j++){

        TextView names = (TextView) empFirstName.getTag(j);
        System.out.println("Name is "+names.getText());

    }
```

But it's throwing null pointer exception!!

Answer (score 0):

You can set a tag to each view as you create them and compare  tags later when needed.

Answer (score 0):

You want to search for the row or the contents of the Row ? If its the row then set a tag for the row. Something like :

```
row.setTag(SomeTag);
```

Define an ids file under res/values. Add this to that :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <item type="id" name="sample_key" />
</resources>
```

In the java file ref. it like this :

```
String sampleKey = "This is a sample key";
textView.setTag(R.id.sample_key, sampleKey);

String returnedString = (String) textView.getTag(R.id.sample_key);
```

Comment: I need to search for contents of the row. Situation is I'm having a table layout and for each row it contains name and his code. There is an edit text view, where I can enter his name and search for him in the table layout.

Comment: You can add a tag for textview having the name and the code. then use the textview.getTag(somekey) and then do textview.getText();

Comment: Could you please explain in more detail!! I'm unable to retrieve the text associated with that tag!!

Comment: How do I iterate through all the values? It's returning just last value!!

Comment: For each row that you add to the layout dynamically, you would add a different key. then you would iterate thru' the keys.